# Firebase Security Rules for Realtime database

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to set rules for the firebase Realtime Database. Rules are set to

```
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true
```

}
This makes it public but I want to set it to private and I want to access it. Not only through the console but the Angular app.

Comment: I recommend reading this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security, and watching the video linked in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to login to get an `auth` object and then can use the user-id to restrict access:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#authentication

Comment: I am new to firebase, so where do I get the AUTH object please? Can you give some more details? I have read the link you sent but couldn't manage to work it out.

Comment: @Sz2013 You need to implement authentication first, study the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth